# Anova of treatment effects by factor within a single data frame

Tags: r, anova

I feel like this should be an easy problem to solve but I'm having no luck, so here goes.

I have a large data set (6,000 or so entries) containing control and treatment data for 40 species of tree. I'd like to run an `anova` to determine the effects of the treatment on each species. I guess this would be like running a `one-way anova` to determine treatment effects using 40 different `data frames`, but I don't want to have to `subset`. I'm not interested in any interaction terms, I just want to know how each species is affected by the treatment.

Here's some dummy data to play with

```
# Generate species 
species <- rep (c("Oak", "Elm", "Ash"), each = 10)

# Generate treatments
dose_1 <- rep (c("Ctrl"), 30)
dose_2 <- rep (c ("L"), 30)

# Generate results
result_1 <- c((runif(10, 9, 12)), runif(10, 14, 16), runif(10, 6, 8), (runif(10, 2, 5)), runif(10, 1, 4), runif(10, 2, 4))

# Combine into a sinlge dataframe
data <- data.frame (SPECIES = rep(species, 2), TREATMENT = c(dose_1, dose_2), RESULT = result_1)
```

From here, I'd like to run a `one-way anova` for treatment effects for each species, a bit like this, but without having to `subset`

```
model <- aov (RESULT ~ TREATMENT, data = subset (data, SPECIES == 'Oak'))

summary(model)
```

Help....

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
results <- lapply(split(data, data$SPECIES), function(d){summary(aov(RESULT ~ TREATMENT, data=data))})
```